# Can DocuSign API read history statuses?

Tags: docusignapi

I need to identify all the envelopes from the past year where the email address was corrected.  The current status of the envelopes could be anything, but I need to access the historical status of 'corrected'.

I have looked at the online reports but they just look at current status.  I have looked at https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/listauditevents/ but it does not list 'corrected' as an event.
Someone else posted in the DocuSign community the same question a few years ago but was not provided a solution.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I've asked my engineering colleagues to see if this is possible via the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleagues tell me that listAuditEvents should give you the information. More information:

`audit_events` will provide this information. `Corrected` is not a status but an action taken. The status is still `sent`. Example output:

```
{
    "name": "Action",
    "value": "Corrected"
},
{
    "name": "Message",
    "value": "Dina DocuSign changed the e-mail address dine+ABC@XYZ.com to dine+correct@XYZ.com"
},
{
    "name": "EnvelopeStatus",
    "value": "sent"
},
```